# three.js - Texture on plane with an opening

Tags: object, three.js, textures

I try to cover few of my gallery walls with a simple texture. As far as it concerns simple plane or rectangular shape there is no problem, but in case of a wall with an opening - unwanted effects appear. This is a link to the gallery: http://galleryingrey.com.

Can anyone help me to finad some (not to much sophisticated) solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to research UV coordinates and how they work.

Comment: It was not to much sophisticated indeed :). Thx